# How to make a javascript FOR LOOP wait for certain conditions before looping

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback

I have to call up a function (checkImdb) that will fetch some info from a php file (temp.php) and put some contents on a div (placeToFetchTo). This has to be done a certain amount of times, so I used a FOR LOOP for that.
The problem is that only the last instance of the looped counter (currentCastId) gets used. I understand there needs to be a way to force the FOR LOOP to wait for the fetch to be complete, and I have been looking online for answers but nothing seems to work so far. I apologise if I have missed an eventual answer that already exists.
Any help is appreciated.
This is the code I am referring to:

```
function checkImdb (totalCasts) {
    $(function() {
        for (currentCastId = 1; currentCastId <= totalCasts; currentCastId++) {
                //Gets cast IMDB#
                var row = document.getElementById("area2-" + currentCastId)
                row = row.innerHTML.toString();
                var fetchThis = "temp.php?id=" + row + "\ .filmo-category-section:first b a";
                placeToFetchTo = "#area0-" + currentCastId;

                function load_complete() {
                    var filhos = $(placeToFetchTo).children().length, newDiv ="";
                    var nrMoviesMissing = 0, looped = 0;
                            alert("done- "+ placeToFetchTo);

                }

                document.getElementById("area0").innerHTML = document.getElementById("area0").innerHTML + "<div id=\"area0-" + currentCastId + "\"></div>";

                $(placeToFetchTo).load(fetchThis, null, load_complete);

        } //End of: for (imdbLooper = 0; imdbLooper <= totalCasts; imdbLooper++) {

    }); //End of: $(function() {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*2017 update*: The original answer had the callback arg as last arg in the function signature. However, now that the ES6 spread operator is a real thing, best practice is to put it *first*, not *last*, so that the spread operator can be used to capture "everything else".

---

You don't really want to use a for loop if you need to do any "waiting". Instead, use self-terminating recursion:

```
/**
 * This is your async function that "does things" like
 * calling a php file on the server through GET/POST and
 * then deals with the data it gets back. After it's done,
 * it calls the function that was passed as "callback" argument.
 */
function doAsynchronousStuff(callback, ...) {
  //... your code goes here ...

  // as final step, on the "next clock tick",
  // call the "callback" function. This makes
  // it a "new" call, giving the JS engine some
  // time to slip in other important operations
  // in its thread. This basically "unblocks"
  // JS execution.
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    callback(/* with whatever args it needs */);
  });
}

/**
 * This is your "control" function, responsible
 * for calling your actual worker function as
 * many times as necessary. We give it a number that
 * tells it how many times it should run, and a function
 * handle that tells it what to call when it has done
 * all its iterations.
 */
function runSeveralTimes(fnToCallWhenDone, howManyTimes) {
  // if there are 0 times left to run, we don't run
  // the operation code, but instead call the "We are done"
  // function that was passed as second argument.
  if (howManyTimes === 0) {
   return fnToCallWhenDone();
  }

  // If we haven't returned, then howManyTimes is not
  // zero. Run the real operational code once, and tell
  // to run this control function when its code is done:
  doAsynchronousStuff(function doThisWhenDone() {
    // the "when done with the real code" function simply
    // calls this control function with the "how many times?"
    // value decremented by one. If we had to run 5 times,
    // the next call will tell it to run 4 times, etc.
    runSeveralTimes(fnToCallWhenDone, howManyTimes - 1);
  }, ...);
}
```

In this code the `doAsynchronousStuff` function is your actual code.

The use of `requestAnimationFrame` is to ensure the call doesn't flood the callstack. Since the work is technically independent, we can schedule it to be called "on the next tick" instead.

The call chain is a bit like this:

```
// let's say we need to run 5 times
runSeveralTimes(5);
=> doAsynchronousStuff()
   => runSeveralTimes(5-1 = 4)
      => this is on a new tick, on a new stack, so
         this actually happens as if a "new" call:
runSeveralTimes(4)
=> doAsynchronousStuff()
   => runSeveralTimes(4-1 = 3), on new stack
runSeveralTimes(3)
...
=> doAsynchronousStuff()
   => runSeveralTimes(1-1 = 0), on new stack
runSeveralTimes(0)
=> fnToCallWhenDone()
=> return
<end of call chain>
```

Comment: I have to admit I am totally lost with your solution. I am not an advanced coder.

Comment: I'll add some comments to the answer anyway so you can see whether you r understanding matches the description =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a while loop and have the loop exit only when all your fetches have completed.

```
function checkImdb (totalCasts) {
 currentCastId = 1;
 totalCasts = 3;
 doneLoading = false;

 while (!doneLoading)
 { 
       //do something
       currentCastId++;

      if (currentCastId == totalCasts)
           doneLoading = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: that means your done loading condition is never being switched to true